# Tag Burn: Independent-Contractor

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I've proposed to delete [independent-contractor](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/independent-contractor) from [How should an independent contractor's resume differ from that of a candidate seeking a permanent position?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/271/how-should-an-independent-contractors-resume-differ-from-that-of-a-candidate-se)

Such a tag adds nothing on Freelancing.SE and I nominate it for burning!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get to [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) something!

Done; if a tag isn't actually on anything, after a while it will be deleted automagically.

If this pops up again and again, I can ask the devs to blacklist it.